# How can I set a link to my gym so that siri can find it

Tags: ios, contacts, siri

I want to set a reminder like "remember me to change dress when I am at the gym".
Siri answers "I do not know your gym. Touch your name to add the gym to your record".

I could not find a way to do that. Using a custom label did not work, nor when I used the label "others".

Siri works fine when i say "remember me to ... when i am at Jane Doe".

Answer (score 2):

Create a contact entry for your gym with phone number, website, and address. You can put the name of the gym in the company field and then you can create a nickname that just says "Gym"... problem is that Gym and Jim sound alike.

What I now tried was setting up a new address to my person vCard with a custom tag. I have gym now as a customer address on my card and why I say "Get to directions to gym" it worked.

[image]

With having the gym as a separate contact entry, does it work when you say the Gym's name?

Comment: I tried as you told me, but it didn't work using the nickname.

Comment: I apologise that the nickname thing didn't work but adding the address and Custom Label to your vCard should do the trick.

Comment: @hkk - does Siri type gym when you say it or some other string? Depending on accents and locales, you might have to pick a more audibly distinct name like workout or gg or something else you find easy to remember.

Comment: @bmike - actually Siri and I are talking in german. But when I say "gym" Siri uses the translated word "Fitnessstudio".

Comment: @Andrew U. - adding the address to my vCard is not an option: when sending my vCard the recipient will not need this informantion.